# Stored Procedure Update is working fine but not data is not getting inserted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
USE [Database]
GO    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [INF_SP_GET_INSERTFIELDS2]  
    @Menu_Id INT= NULL,  
    @Created_By  int,
    @dtInsert INF_UDTT_Menu_Key_Rights2 Readonly 
As  
BEGIN  
    Declare @dtTR_Local INF_UDTT_Menu_Key_Rights2  

    INSERT INTO @dtTR_Local  
       SELECT 
           isnull(DTL.Key_ID,0) as pkid,
           dtc.Key_Name, dtc.Description, 
           dtc.Module_Id, dtc.Key_Enabled, dtc.Menu_Id 
       FROM 
           @dtInsert dtc  
       LEFT JOIN 
           INF_LIB_Module_Keys DTL ON dtc.PKID = DTL.Key_ID 
                                    AND DTL.Menu_Id = @Menu_Id  

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT INF_LIB_Module_Keys ON

    UPDATE TBL1 
    SET TBL1.pkid = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(pkid), 0) 
                     FROM @dtTR_Local) + ROWNUM 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TBL.pkid) ROWNUM, * 
         FROM @dtTR_Local TBL 
         WHERE pkid = 0) TBL1  

    MERGE INF_LIB_Module_Keys TRG  
    USING (SELECT * FROM @dtTR_Local) SRC ON SRC.PKID = TRG.Key_Id 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
       UPDATE 
           SET TRG.Module_Id = SRC.Module_Id,
               TRG.Key_Name = SRC.Key_Name,
               TRG.Description = SRC.Description,
               TRG.Key_enabled = SRC.Key_enabled

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
       INSERT (Key_Id, Key_Name, Description, Module_Id, Key_enabled, Menu_Id)  
       VALUES ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Key_Id), 0) 
                FROM INF_LIB_Module_Keys) + SRC.pkid, SRC.Key_Name,
               SRC.Description, SRC.Module_Id, SRC.Key_enabled, SRC.Menu_Id);     

    select @Menu_Id   
END
```

Comment: @dtInsert INF_UDTT_Menu_Key_Rights2 is User defined table type

Comment: When you run this script you just update you stored procedur ebut you wont run it. You can run it with: EXEC INF_SP_GET_INSERTFIELDS2

Comment: Stored procedure is fine. In this SP there are two parts(Insert and update).Insert part is not working

Comment: not working? you mean it isn't inserting data? There are two inserts. Which one isn't inserting? the merge or the insert?

Comment: The Insert...The merge is working fine

Comment: Data is coming fine in Temp table(UDDT) but not insertion is not working

Answer (score -1):

It appears you're inserting a primary id (pkid), but didn't turn Indentity_Insert ON for INF_UDTT_Menu_Key_Rights2?